# Trouble with Python to APK API=36

Tags: python, android, api, kivy, buildozer

I am attempting to get permission to read and write files for android API level 36 Android 13. Building using Python Kivy p4a and buildozer. I understand I am not calling the permission correctly but can not find or possibly understand how to get past the permissions stage. I am new to Kivy and Android. I choose Python because I have Python background with Pandas.
The app loads to the tablet and asks the user for permission and then crashes.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
from jnius import autoclass
from android import activity
from kivy.config import Config
from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path

# keep the app awake when running - do not let it go dark
Config.set('kivy', 'android.wakelock', 'True')

# Request external storage permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

# Get the full path to the text file in your Android device's WB directory
storage_path = primary_external_storage_path()
file_path = storage_path + '/WB/Hello.txt'

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create a box layout
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Create a button with the text "Good Day"
        button = Button(text='Good Day')
        button.bind(on_press=self.on_button_press)

        # Create a label for displaying text from the file
        self.label = Label(text='Do Nothing Label')

        # Add the button and label to the layout
        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(self.label)

        return layout

    def on_button_press(self, button):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            content = f.read()

        # Display the contents of the text file in the label
        self.label.text = content

        # Write to the text file
        with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write('Success')

def request_documents_permission():
    Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
    DocumentsContract = autoclass('android.provider.DocumentsContract')
    Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
    Build = autoclass('android.os.Build')
    if Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT:
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Uri.parse(get_storage_dir()))
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 42)

def get_storage_dir():
    Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

def create_folder(folder_name):
    File = autoclass('java.io.File')
    folder_path = get_storage_dir() + '/' + folder_name
    folder = File(folder_path)
    folder.mkdirs()

    # Create the "Hello.txt" file if it doesn't exist
    file_path = folder_path + '/Hello.txt'
    hello_file = File(file_path)
    if not hello_file.exists():
        hello_file.createNewFile()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    request_documents_permission()
    create_folder('WB')
    MyApp().run()
```

I tried the above code. I was able to understand that my code will not work with higher levels of API but was not able to find code that will work.

Comment: Android 13 is API 33. https://apilevels.com/